# Simple INI file parser in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, file, configuration

I've written a rudimentary parser for [INI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) files:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings   #-}

import qualified Data.Map           as M
import           Data.Maybe         (fromMaybe)
import qualified Data.Text          as T

type Ini = M.Map T.Text Section

data Section =
  Section
    { name       :: T.Text
    , properties :: M.Map T.Text T.Text
    }
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = parseIni iniFilePath >>= \ini -> putStrLn $ "Parsed INI: " ++ show ini
  where
    iniFilePath = "/home/me/test.ini"

parseIni :: FilePath -> IO Ini
parseIni iniFilePath = parseToIni . T.pack <$> readFile iniFilePath

parseToIni :: T.Text -> Ini
parseToIni stringToParse =
  -- We return the parsed Ini, not the helper values
  firstOfTriple $
  foldr
    (\line (ini, currentSectionMaybe, lineIndex) ->
        -- We're at a new section start or the end of the file → add the previous section
        -- to the parsed Ini value and create a new section
      if isSectionHeader line || lineIndex >= length lines - 1
        then let updatedIni = addSection ini currentSectionMaybe
              in (updatedIni, Just $ Section (getSectionName line) M.empty, 1 + lineIndex)
        else (ini, updateSection currentSectionMaybe line, 1 + lineIndex))
    (M.empty, Nothing, 0) $
  -- Since foldr is right associative we would process the lines starting with the last one, that's
  -- why we reverse the list of lines
  reverse lines
  where
    lines :: [T.Text]
    lines = T.splitOn "\n" stringToParse

firstOfTriple :: (a, b, c) -> a
firstOfTriple (x, _, _) = x

parseProperty :: T.Text -> Maybe (T.Text, T.Text)
parseProperty line =
  case T.splitOn "=" line of
    [name, value] -> Just (T.strip name, T.strip value)
    _             -> Nothing

updateSection :: Maybe Section -> T.Text -> Maybe Section
updateSection sectionMaybe line = fmap updateSection' sectionMaybe
  where
    updateSection' :: Section -> Section
    updateSection' section =
      -- Add the property to the section if the property can be parsed.
      -- Otherwise, leave the section as it were
      maybe
        section
        (\(propName, value) -> Section (name section) (M.insert propName value (properties section)))
        (parseProperty line)

getSectionName :: T.Text -> T.Text
getSectionName line = fromMaybe line headerWithoutBracketsMaybe
  where
    headerWithoutBracketsMaybe = T.stripPrefix "[" line >>= T.stripSuffix "]"

isSectionHeader :: T.Text -> Bool
isSectionHeader line = T.isPrefixOf "[" strippedLine && T.isSuffixOf "]" strippedLine
  where
    strippedLine = T.strip line

addSection :: Ini -> Maybe Section -> Ini
addSection ini sectionMaybe = maybe ini (\section -> M.insert (name section) section ini) sectionMaybe
```

I'd love to get feedback on how to simplify the code and/or make it more readable.

Things I'm aware of and ok with at the moment:

- The parser doesn't support comments
- `addSection` could be eta-reduced
- I don't use a parsing library like Parsec
- I don't use lenses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few comments – not a full review:

1. `parseToIni :: T.Text -> Ini` indicates that from any random string, `parseToIni` can produce an `Ini`. This makes me wonder how it would handle an invalid `.ini` file, or e.g. the string `foo`.
2. In `updateSection :: Maybe Section -> T.Text -> Maybe Section` the `Maybe`s obfuscate what the function is supposed to do. Can the function produce a `Nothing` if the first argument is a `Just`? Better remove the `Maybe`s and `fmap` the whole thing if needed. `addSection` is similar.
3. `main` would IMHO be more readable if it simply used `do`-notation.
4. In `parseToIni`, the worker function for `foldr` is complex enough that it should have a type annotation. It's ok to to simply call inner worker functions `f` IMHO.
5. I think it's a bit confusing that the section names appear both as the keys of `Ini` *and* in `Section`'s `name` field. I'd probably remove the `name` field.
6. A few type synonyms for keys, values, section names etc might help with readability.
7. The order of parameters in `addSection` and `updateSection` is a bit unconventional. The usual `a -> b -> b` ordering is a bit nicer for partial applications.
8. IMHO, `maybe` (and similar functions like `either`) don't aid readability. If you don't want to come up with a variable name, try the `LambdaCase` extension.
9. Try [`Data.Text.IO.readFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.1/docs/Data-Text-IO.html#v:readFile).
10. Instead of `getSectionName` and `isSectionName`, have a single function of type `Text` -> `Maybe SectionName`.

All in all I think your code is pretty readable. It's mostly the types that could be a bit better.

Answer (score 4):

I know you said you were fine with not using a parser combinator library like parsec, but I thought you might like to see the how the same thing might look using one, so I wrote an Attoparsec based parser for your data types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module IniParser where

import           Control.Monad               ( void )
import           Data.Attoparsec.Text        ( Parser
                                             , char
                                             , endOfInput
                                             , endOfLine
                                             , many'
                                             , many1
                                             , notInClass
                                             , parseOnly
                                             , satisfy
                                             , space
                                             )
import           Data.Map.Strict             ( Map )
import qualified Data.Map.Strict      as Map
import           Data.Text                   ( Text
                                             , pack
                                             )
import           System.Environment          ( getArgs )

type Ini = Map Text Section

data Section = Section
  { name       :: Text
  , properties :: Map Text Text
  } deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [path] <- getArgs
  parseIniFile path >>= \case
    Right ini -> putStrLn $ "Parsed INI: " ++ show ini
    Left err  -> putStrLn $ "ERROR parsing ini: " ++ err

parseIniFile :: FilePath -> IO (Either String Ini)
parseIniFile iniFilePath = parseIni . pack <$> readFile iniFilePath

parseIni :: Text -> Either String Ini
parseIni = parseOnly ini

ini :: Parser Ini
ini = do
  defaultSection <- lexeme (Section "" <$> (Map.fromList <$> many' property))
  namedSections  <- lexeme (many' section)
  void $ endOfInput
  let allSections | null (properties defaultSection) = namedSections
                  | otherwise = defaultSection:namedSections
  pure . Map.fromList . map (\section -> (name section, section))
    $ allSections

section :: Parser Section
section = Section <$> sectionName <*> (Map.fromList <$> many' (lexeme property))

sectionName :: Parser Text
sectionName = char '[' *> sectionNameChars <* char ']' <* endOfLine

sectionNameChars :: Parser Text
sectionNameChars = pack <$> many' (satisfy $ notInClass "]\r\n")

property :: Parser (Text, Text)
property = (,) <$> propertyName <*> (lexeme (char '=') *> propertyValue)

propertyName :: Parser Text
propertyName = pack <$> many' (satisfy $ notInClass "=\r\n\t ")

propertyValue :: Parser Text
propertyValue = pack <$> many' (satisfy $ notInClass "\r\n")

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme p = whitespace *> p <* whitespace

whitespace :: Parser String
whitespace = many' space
```

I think the main strength of the approach is self pretty self-evident.  It eliminates all the multi-line lambdas, the entire foldr, etc. which (at least IMHO) really obscures the essence of what the code is expressing.

Additionally I've restricted the use of qualified imports to a single one usage where I think it makes the code more readable, though your taste may vary.

You can see the whole stack based [project here](https://github.com/lgastako/ini-parser) if you're interested.